# Korach vs Elitzafan - what's the big deal?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshat-korach

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.16.1?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.16.1.4&lang2=he&w2=all&lang3=he) on Korach's claims:

> וּמָה רָאָה קֹרַח לַחֲלֹק עִם מֹשֶׁה?
>   נִתְקַנֵּא עַל נְשִׂיאוּתוֹ שֶׁל אֱלִיצָפָן בֶּן עֻזִּיאֵל,
>   שֶׁמִּנָּהוּ מֹשֶׁה נָשִׂיא עַל בְּנֵי קְהָת עַל פִּי הַדִּבּוּר

From this explanation, Korach did accept Moses and Aharon's roles and their leadership and only questioned other positions within the tribe of Levy, specifically Elitzafan as the supervision. So why was Korach's Machlokes so dramatic?

As we see in the beginning of Bemidbar the Nessi'im were clearly G-d chosen and I don't see Korach questioning G-d in His decisions.

Were the whole mess and the death of close to 15 thousand Jews justified by such a minor disagreement?

Answer (score 2):

You need to continue reading Rashi.

While Korach may have originally accepted the positions of Moshe and Aharon, and was motivated by jealousy of Elitzafan's promotion, this caused him to attempt to undermine the entirety of Moshe's authority:

> אָמַר קֹרַח ... הֲרֵינִי חוֹלֵק עָלָיו וּמְבַטֵּל אֶת דְּבָרָיו. מֶה עָשָׂה? עָמַד וְכָנַס ר"נ רָאשֵׁי סַנְהֶדְרָאוֹת ... הִתְחִילוּ לִשְׂחֹק עָלָיו‏
>
> Korach said, "I will argue against him [Moshe] and undermine his words."
>
> What did he do? He gathered 250 heads of the Sanhedrin ... they began to mock him [Moshe].

Comment: You have a tendency of quoting without explaining. As I mentioned, "* the Nessi'im were clearly G-d chosen*" so I don't understand what fighting Moses would help in moving Elitzafan out? Sometimes the Midrash is simply beyond my comprehension.

Comment: How do you know that Korach believed that Elitzafan’s appointment was from G-d?